# I am trying to delete a note in react but I am getting an error that you cannot access new notes before initialization?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**React**
Find error in delete note function that can't acces the newNotes befor initialization thats why that note can not be deleted?

The deleteNote function is working because its console log the message with the id that i written in it but it does'not delete the note,I already declare the newNote and initial the value in it but i can't understand why it gave the error?

```
    const [notes, setNotes] = useState(notesInitial) 
    //Add Note
    const addNote = (title, description, tag) => {
        //TODO API CALL
        console.log("adding a new note");
        const note = {
            "_id": "63074e71318fac99be7ce65a",
            "user": "62ee8f0b86e5c4946d3b75d5",
            "title": title,
            "description": description,
            "tag": tag,
            "date": "2022-08-25T10:26:57.324Z",
            "__v": 0
        };
        setNotes(notes.concat(note));
    }



    //Delete A Note
    const deleteNote = (id) => {

        console.log("The node delteing with id" + id);
        I think I missing something here
        const newNotes = newNotes.filter((notes) => { return notes._id !== id })
        setNotes(newNotes);
    }




    return (
        <noteContext.Provider value={{ notes, addNote, deleteNote, editNote }}>
            {props.children}
        </noteContext.Provider>
    )

}


export default NoteState;
```

Comment: You are accessing `newNotes` before initialization. You should filter on `notes` in the deleteNote method.

Comment: you should give a different name to constant in deleteNote.....const newNotes "newNotes" is already declared

Answer (score 1):

yes you made mistake here so convert it from

```
 //Delete A Note
    const deleteNote = (id) => {

        console.log("The node delteing with id" + id);
        I think I missing something here
        const newNotes = newNotes.filter((notes) => { return notes._id !== id })
        setNotes(newNotes);
    }
```

to

```
const deleteNote = (id) => {

        console.log("The node delteing with id" + id);
        I think I missing something here
        const newNotes = notes.filter((note) => { return note._id !== id })
        setNotes(newNotes);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const newNotes = newNotes.filter((notes) => { return notes._id !== id })
```

`newNotes` are being declared again and it won't take from your `useState` one.
In the `deleteNode` function name it anything else.

```js
const deleteNote = (id) => {

        console.log("The node delteing with id" + id);
        I think I missing something here
        const newNotes2 = notes.filter((notes) => { return notes._id !== id })
        setNotes(newNotes2);
    }
```